# adding new admin page to backend(magento 2)

Tags: magento2, admin, module, magento-2.0, admin-controller

I can get into the `execute()` function if I do not run the construct function. but I cannot find the bug in my `__construct` function.
The file is `\app\code\Cleargo\Contactus\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\Index.php`

```
namespace Cleargo\Contactus\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Index extends  Action

{
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Cleargo_Contactus::add_row';

protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
){
     parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

public function execute()
{

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Department'));

    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

Comment: the result of above code is a completely empty page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try same as above code,

```
namespace Cleargo\Contactus\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;


class Index extends  \Magento\Backend\App\Action

{
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Cleargo_Contactus::add_row';

protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
){
     parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

public function execute()
{

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Department'));

    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

After adding same code and **`you must have to remove var folder from root`** and deploy command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: it display an error : 'Class Cleargo\Contactus\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid\        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context does not exist'

Comment: i have updated my answer plz remove var folder and try again

Comment: it works! THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `_isAllowed` method to your admin controller action to check the permissions to run it.

Assuming that your constant `ADMIN_RESOURCE` corresponds to the ACL resource you declared for this route, you should add the following code to your action class:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed(self::ADMIN_RESOURCE);
}
```

Comment: it does not work for mine

Comment: protected function _isAllowed is already inherited from parent class